# Bash/zsh insert history / ctrl-R inline?

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

Ctrl-R in bash and zsh is very useful. So is the `!!` alias - which expands to the last command. I often find myself doing things like: `cat file | !!`, before pressing tab to tweak the command. I would like to search my history incrementally when using `!!`, but ctrl-R only seems to work at an empty prompt.

Is there a way to insert historic commands somewhere other than the beginning of a line?

**Approaches tried:**

I tried `$(fc -nl | fzf) TAB` but this quoted the last command. I could use something like a zle plugin (like I used in [this](https://github.com/facetframer/zshnip/blob/master/zshnip.zsh)) but it feels like overkill...

Answer (score 1):

I usually first search back with `reverse-search-history` (ctrl-r) to find
the wanted line, then use `beginning-of-line` (ctrl-a) and `kill-line`
(ctrl-k) to copy the line into the kill ring, then interrupt with ctrl-C so
as not to disturb the history. I can then type my command, `cat file |`,
and `yank` (ctrl-y) the last kill at the appropriate point.

If I've already started typing the command, I go to the beginning of the
line, add a `#`, and press enter to put it in the history, then do the
search back, and, after the interrupt, recover the commented line from the
history.

Comment: You can just use `^U` to copy the whole line. But why not just `^A` and insert `<file` there?

Comment: The `cat file |` is just the example from the OP. Presumably, something more complicated might be wanted.